# Bcrypt Hash Returns TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing") and Invalid Salt

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt, salt

I've looked at all the StackOverflow questions related to this but I just cannot seem to figure this out. When I hash a password, and check it against itself, it returns the TypeError "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" with the current code:

```
from scripts import tabledef
from flask import session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from contextlib import contextmanager
import bcrypt

(Unrelated Python code...)

def hash_password(password):
     return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())


def credentials_valid(username, password):
    with session_scope() as s:
        user = s.query(tabledef.User).filter(
            tabledef.User.username.in_([username])).first()
        if user:

            return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password)
        else:
            return False
```

When I try and fix this error by setting `user.password= user.password.encode('utf8')`, I get "Invalid Salt".

What is wrong with this code?

UPDATE: 
I am storing the passwords through Flask input from the user:

```
import json
import sys
import os
import plotly
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go


from scripts import tabledef
from scripts import forms
from scripts import helpers
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash, Markup
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.form)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.form['username'].lower()
            password = request.form['password']
            if form.validate():
                if helpers.credentials_valid(username, password):
                    session['logged_in'] = True
                    session['username'] = username
                    session['email'] = request.form['email']
                    session['password'] = request.form['password']
                    return json.dumps({'status': 'Login successful'})
                return json.dumps({'status': 'Invalid user/pass'})
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Both fields required'})
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    user = helpers.get_user()
    return render_template('home.html', user=user)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.form)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.form['username'].lower()
            password = helpers.hash_password(request.form['password'])
            email = request.form['email']
            if form.validate():
                if not helpers.username_taken(username):
                    helpers.add_user(username, password, email)
                    session['logged_in'] = True
                    session['username'] = username
                    session['email'] = request.form['email']
                    session['password'] = request.form['password']
                    return json.dumps({'status': 'Signup successful'})
                return json.dumps({'status': 'Username taken'})
            return json.dumps({'status': 'User/Pass required'})
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

This is the error I get:

```
/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/suraj/Documents/Programming/current-projects/GW_Dining_Tracker/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/suraj/Documents/Programming/current-projects/GW_Dining_Tracker/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/suraj/Documents/Programming/current-projects/GW_Dining_Tracker/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/suraj/Documents/Programming/current-projects/GW_Dining_Tracker/Flaskex-master/app.py", line 34, in login
    if helpers.credentials_valid(username, password):
  File "/home/suraj/Documents/Programming/current-projects/GW_Dining_Tracker/Flaskex-master/scripts/helpers.py", line 64, in credentials_valid
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password)
  File "/home/suraj/Documents/Programming/current-projects/GW_Dining_Tracker/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 101, in checkpw
    raise TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking")
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking
```

Comment: the first function should have a tab for the return. That was a mistake typing it up, I apologize.

Comment: Please post the full exception, not just the description, and provide a runnable sample so we can reproduce the error ourselves. See [mcve] in the help for more, but if you don't do at least one of those two, we have to guess which line might be producing that error.

Comment: Also, you're not showing us how your store `user.password`. But the fact that it's not a `bytes` (because otherwise the `encode` that you tried would be raising an `AttributeError`) means it obviously isn't the result that came back from `hash_password`, so… what is it?

Comment: Are you by any chance storing the actual password as `user.password`, instead of its bcrypt of it? If so: you never want to do that; the whole point of using bcrypt (or any password hasher) is that you don't need to keep actual user passwords around somewhere they can be leaked from.

Comment: I added edits to show how I store the passwords. I also included the error I receive. But I store the password as a hash into the database. The database type for the password is simple a Column(String()) if that helps.

Comment: The SQLAlchemy [`String`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String) type is meant for handling Unicode strings, not byte strings. That's why you're getting the error. And just adding `encode('utf8')` may or may not fix the problem. If you use a type meant for byte strings, like `Binary`/`BINARY`/`VARBINARY`/`BLOB`, does the problem still happen?

Comment: Okay so when I make the tables, I should call it Columb(Binary()) as the password?

Comment: I think that's right. At least try it and see what happens.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Any way to upvote or check your comment as complete?

Comment: I’ll write an answer when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking the value from a SQLAlchemy `String` column and passing it to `bcrypt.checkpw`. `String` is intended for Unicode strings, it provides values as `str`. But `bcrypt` only works on byte strings, so it expects a `bytes`. That's what the `TypeError` that says "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" is telling you.

Depending on what database backend and DB-API library you're using (and, for some backends, on how your database is configured), when you save a `bytes` value `s` to a `String` column, it might save `s.decode()`, in which case you could just use `user.password.encode()` to get the same bytes back—but it might not. For example, it could also just save, say, `str(s)`. In which case, if the hash were the `bytes` value `b'abcd'`, the column value would be the string `"b'abcd'"`, so and calling `encode` on that gets you `b"b'abcd'"`, not `b'abcd'`.

The cleanest way to handle this is to use a `Binary` column<sup>1</sup>—or, maybe better, `Binary(60)`<sup>2</sup>—to store your hashes, instead of a `String` column. Any DB-API that supports `Binary` will just store a `bytes` as-is, and return it as a `bytes`, which is exactly what you want.

---

<sub>1. `Binary` is an optional type. If it isn't present for your DB-ABI, the same type may be available as `BINARY`. If not, look through [the list of types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html) and try other types that inherit from `_Binary`. The ones without "large" in their name or acronym will probably be more efficient, but otherwise any of them should work.</sub>

<sub>2. With the default settings, `bcrypt` printable digests will always be exactly 60 bytes. Databases can generally store fixed-width fields like `BINARY(60)` more compactly, and search them more quickly than variable-width fields like `VARBINARY`. Just using plain `BINARY` may be fine, but it may also work like `VARBINARY`, or it may waste space and work like `BINARY(255)`, etc.</sub>

Comment: I had this exact same issue - encoding error leading to salt error. Weird since I followed the docs exactly and I have no customization on top of a very the basic use case. I'm annoyed with bcrypt and sqlAlchemy that I got this error and had to change my DB column to binary with such a basic use case. I'm thankful for this question and the answer! It would have been hard to debug otherwise.